# Deleting an iOS App with documents in the iCloud-enabled folder

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, icloud

I found out that if I delete an App from the device, all local documents are deleted of course, but if the App has files stored in the iCloud-enabled folder (`[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil]`) - These files are not deleted.

This causes two problems:

- The storage taken by these files is not freed.
- If the user re-installs the App, there are already files in the folder, which disrupts normal initialization.

I can take care of the second issue by going through the directory on first launch and deleting everything in there, but it seems a bit awkward.

I can't think of a way to take care of the first issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS automatically purges files in the iCloud directory to free up space. You may also specifically "evict" files from your app, but since you are addressing the scenario in which the app is deleted, that probably won't be much help.

See the videos at developer.apple.com/icloud for more info.

Comment: This may be true in the long run, but I checked (on a jailbroken device) and found out that the App folder and all the files in it still exist under Mobile Documents several days after the App is removed. And even if the files are deleted after a longer period (or when there's not enough free space on the device), my second issue still holds - if the user re-installs the App, there may already be files in the folder, which disrupts normal initialization. So there's no solution?

Comment: What kind of initialization are you doing? You may want to reconsider that. If it's really an issue, then you could delete those iCloud documents on initialization, but part of the point of iCloud is to have documents around even if the app gets deleted, so that kind of defeats the purpose. Unless I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: Deleting the iCloud documents on initialization will propagate the delete to all other devices, so it's not an option.