# What is the right In-App Purchase product type?

Tags: objective-c, ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am deciding on how to structure my in-app purchase. My goal is to do it *without* my own server infrastructure.

My app generates a report in PDF format that is exported via email. I would like to limit the number of reports to 3, after that one would have to purchase another 3. All the data for the report as well as the report itself is created locally on the device.

Should this be a **`Non-Consumable`** type? Maybe not, because it says in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/APIOverview/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html) that this should be for one time only purchase. But I want the user to be able to purchase another 3 or even 10 reports again. However, it also says this type should be automatically available on all devices where the app is installed which is what I want.

Or should it be a **`Consumable`** type? Again, this does not seem to fit. The docs state that it *"must be purchased each time the user needs that item."*. Conceptually, this seems close, but how do I keep track if, say, 2 reports are consumed on the iPhone, and one should still be available on every device?

I guess we can rule out **`Auto-Renewable Subscription`**.

Maybe it should be a **`Non-Renewable Subscription`**.  However, I do not want my report credits to have an expiration date, and ideally they should propagate  through to all devices, which this type also does not provide.

I am willing to compromise on the all-devices propagation. The credits should be tracked accurately, and it should be possible to purchase an unlimited amount.

How would this be implemented in the app? Just a number in `NSUserDefaults` that is checked before enabling the export button? Is is possible to somehow check via StoreKit each time a report is exported? (It is en email export, so being *online* is a prerequisite anyway).

Is it possible to avoid my own server infrastructure? If not, what would I have to track?

Any thoughts, guidance, recommendations?

Comment: +1 for detailed problem definition.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in Black Frog's answer, relying on Apple's side might be a harder workaround just to avoid server infrastructure. You have to revoke older purchases and make a count for what user spend, and what is left. Even for that you will need a server, I guess.

I will try to put the whole consumable in-app cycle in pieces;

- Implement the client-side of your in-app (iOS)
- For server side you will need; (minimum effort)

  - Two tables, one holding users and their left usage times(credits) and one saving purchase reports
  - Two scripts, (easy on php just few lines) one for decreasing credits, one for saving the receipt information from Apple, as well as verifying it.

Basically you don't need a whole infrastructure to implement the server side of your in-app, so don't let it frighten you. For what I can see, holding onto every information you sell to your user is rather safer than relying on Apple side.

Another important thing to note here is that in-app purchases can be faked and only way to prevent this is to verify the purchased receipt, check out [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/VerifyingStoreReceipts/VerifyingStoreReceipts.html). And also note that this is so much more easier using a php script. If you try to send the retrieved receipt and send it to verifying from the user's device, you are going to implement a whole class for that.

Let me know if you have anything in mind so I will try to go detail.

Comment: That sounds very convincing. I will investigate what I have to do exactly on the server side and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't want to create your own server infrastructure, the user won't have the best experience using your app.  Forget for a minute the different types of in-app purchases. Let say you keep track the number of reports the user can generate on the device in an encrypted file.  Let say the file is located in `NSApplicationSupportDirectory`.

Excerpt from Apple Docs on [Determining Where to Store Your App-Specific Files](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html):

- Resource and data files that your app creates and manages for the user. You might use this directory to store app state information, computed or downloaded data, or even user created data that you manage on behalf of the user.
- Autosave files.
- In iOS, the contents of this directory are backed up by iTunes.

So every time the user does an in-app purchase you increase the count by the amount.  And whenever the user generate a document, I decrease it. And with iCloud, this information is on all the devices the user owns.

This is where the bad user experience can occur. Let's say I have one device and I purchase 5 reports.  I use only 2.  Let's say my device is out of storage and I want to remove your app temporary.  When I install it again, I have lost the 3 reports I have on credit.  This is why you need a server to keep track/history of purchases and when a report was generated.

Comment: I like your approach. Could I not track the number of credits with some key-value store in iCloud in order to get around the reinstallation problem? But maybe that is not reliable, as Apple does not guarantee immediate propagation.

Comment: Let's say I have an app that save 100 MB in iCloud.  And I remove the app from my device because I really don't want it anymore.  I wouldn't want that data to live around forever in iCloud.  It will be counted against my storage limit. Take a look here: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431115/deleting-an-ios-app-with-documents-in-the-icloud-enabled-folder)

Comment: You will need to have a full disclaimer about in-app purchase.  Explaining that if they delete the app, they will lose any unused credits for generating reports.

Comment: I don't know how relevant this is. I would store just a few bites (one `NSNumber`). In the post you reference it states that the data does persist - which it should!

Comment: Try it and do some user testing.  I haven't saved anything iCloud or done any in-app purchases.